# proper css integration using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question regarding css, I want to set the padding of a class/id using jquery I have a code like this on my jquery which works fine:

```
$('.menu').css({ height: '90px' });
```

However, I need to integrate one of the css code into jquery:

style.css

```
#mainNav > .nav > li.active > a, #mainNav > .nav > li.active {
    padding-top: 10px;
 }
```

I want to change that dynamically using jquery.I did something like this but it doesn't work:

```
$('#mainNav > .nav > li.active > a, #mainNav > .nav > li.active').css({ padding-top: '10px'});
```

How to do this? please help me. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Your jQuery code seems correct to me. Have you wrapped your code in [__document-ready__](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler?

Comment: Are there another alternative solution on the jquery code? example using $('#id').children().children()? something like that?

Comment: I think the problem is with `padding-top`. Instead write like this `paddingTop`. OR `.css("padding-top","10px");`

Comment: Please show your html markup, maybe your selectors do not fit and therefore have no effect. Moreover you could try `.css('padding-top', '10px')`

Comment: @SandeepNayak's answer is the correct one. When you're formatting CSS in Jquery to look like `({attribute: value});`, you need to get rid of the hyphens and capitalize the first letter of the second word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a minus sign in your unquoted key name  (`padding-top`). You have two choices:

- camelCase it: `$('#mainNav > .nav > li.active > a, #mainNav > .nav > li.active').css({ paddingTop: '10px'});`
- quote it: `$('#mainNav > .nav > li.active > a, #mainNav > .nav > li.active').css({ "padding-top": '10px'});`

Both ways work the same way, it's up to you.

Here it is live: http://jsfiddle.net/Zq6J8/

Answer (score 0):

you should quote to padding-top or use paddingTop like this:

```
$('#mainNav > .nav > li.active > a, #mainNav > .nav > li.active').css({ "padding-top": '10px'});
```

or

```
$('#mainNav > .nav > li.active > a, #mainNav > .nav > li.active').css({ paddingTop: '10px'});
```

Comment: Thanks to your answers! It worked! i just change it to css({ paddingTop: '10px'}) as you suggested. And css({ "padding-top": '10px'}); also worked! I just forgot to put quotations on it.

Comment: Btw. @Jarich Why would you select an answer that's a copy of mine? Plagiarism encouragement?